# Rotational Extrusion with React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

> I've also asked this question [on Three.js Discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/rotational-extrusion-with-react-three-fiber/59331).

*Depth Extrusion* seems to be not very difficult in Three.js. However, I'm having a hard time finding any resources on how to do *Rotational Extrusions* through it.

So far the closest I've been able to get was actually *Path Extrusion*, which is contained in [this Three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=extru#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes).

Apparently, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71667100/4756173), `ExtrudeGeometry` actually cannot create rotational geometry? It only seems to do extrusions straight along an axis? If so, that's disappointing, since rotational extrusions are one of the most basic extrusions ever. Maybe there's still a way of doing it through *Path Extrusions*?

Here is an example of path extrusion with React Three Fiber:

```
import {
  Vector3,
  CatmullRomCurve3,
  DoubleSide,
  ExtrudeGeometryOptions,
  Shape,
} from "three";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";

const length = 14,
  width = 2,
  deg = 10,
  thickness = 0.3;
const rad = (deg * Math.PI) / 180;
const offset = Math.min(Math.tan(rad) * width, length / 2);

const shape = new Shape();
shape.moveTo(0, 0);
shape.lineTo(offset, width);
shape.lineTo(length - offset, width);
shape.lineTo(length, 0);
shape.lineTo(0, 0);

/**
 * From [Three.js Geometry Extrude Shapes](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=extru#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes)
 */
const closedSpline = new CatmullRomCurve3([
  new Vector3(-60, -100, 60),
  new Vector3(-60, 20, 60),
  new Vector3(-60, 120, 60),
  new Vector3(60, 20, -60),
  new Vector3(60, -100, -60),
]);
closedSpline.curveType = "catmullrom";
closedSpline.closed = true;

const extrudeSettings: ExtrudeGeometryOptions = {
  curveSegments: 1,
  // Catmull-Rom is a recursive algorithm, it needs steps.
  steps: 100,
  depth: thickness,
  bevelEnabled: false,
  extrudePath: closedSpline,
};

/**
 * References:
 *
 * - [How to Create an Irregular 3D Polygon extruded shape React-Three-Fiber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69438868/4756173)
 * - [2D Shape](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/geometry-2d-f408i?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)
 * - [Brad Woods Demos](https://garden.bradwoods.io/notes/javascript/react/react-three-fiber)
 */
export default function Extrusion() {
  return (
    <main style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Canvas>
        <OrbitControls />
        <mesh>
          <extrudeGeometry
            attach="geometry"
            args={[shape, extrudeSettings]}
          />
          <meshStandardMaterial
            color="red"
            side={DoubleSide}
          />
        </mesh>
      </Canvas>
    </main>
  );
}
```